# Why was await* removed from the async/await proposal?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

The only place it seems to be documented is [this issue thread](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/85) and [the actual specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/). However, the reasoning for the removal isn't posted anywhere I could find.

The new recommended way seems to be `await Promise.all()`, but I'm curious as to why `await*` was removed.

Comment: To whoever voted to close, a changing specification is not opinion based. There is a definitive answer to why it was removed. I'm not asking about the merits of await* vs Promise.all...just why it happened.

Comment: Appears first link is referencing implementation of `await *` at "regenerator"  library?, not es7 ? Specification link references `await` at section _"11.6.2.2Future Reserved Words#

The following tokens are reserved for used as keywords in future language extensions."_ ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, the last revision of the readme [before it was removed](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/commit/e05fc5807b4a0648f941806507dbac6192e1dbb9) already mentions everything in that paragraph:

> #### await* and parallelism
>
> In generators, both `yield` and `yield*` can be used. In async
>   functions, only `await` is allowed. The direct analogoue of `yield*`
>   does not make sense in async functions because it would need to
>   repeatedly await the inner operation, but does not know what value to
>   pass into each await (for `yield*`, it just passes in undefined
>   because iterators do not accept incoming values).
>
> It has been suggested that the syntax could be reused for different
>   semantics - sugar for `Promise.all`. This would accept a value that is
>   an array of Promises, and would (asynchronously) return an array of
>   values returned by the promises. This is expected to be one of the
>   most common Promise-related oprerations that would not yet have syntax
>   sugar after the core of this proposal is available.

So it's no direct analogue to `yield*` as one might expect, it **doesn't really make sense**, it was only a suggestion but **never really included** in the spec proposal.

The consensus was that there is no reason to introduce **more syntactical sugar than necessary**, calling `Promise.all` is not much of a difference.

You can check out the discussions in [issue 8](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/8) or [issue 29](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/29).

Finally, proposals for mightier weapons (parallelism) are still under way. Check out [async iteration](https://github.com/zenparsing/async-iteration/), [async generators](https://github.com/jhusain/asyncgenerator) and [observables](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-observable). There might be some that could use an `await*` keyword much better than for simple arrays of promises.

The `async`/`await` proposal is **minimal** and only introduces the necessary primitives. There is no bikeshedding about possible extensions, which should be discussed separately.